# Number Theory proof based on a cubic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $x,y,z$ are integers such that $x^3 + 5y^3 = 25z^3$, then $x = y = z = 0$.

**What I have so far**

We can first move terms and factor the equation to get $x^3=25z^3-5y^3$, then $x^3=5(5z^3-y^3)$.

Taking the cube root of both sides, we get $x = \sqrt[3]{5(5z^3-y^3)}$, which can also be expressed as $x = 5^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot (5z^3-y^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

**What I'm stuck on**

Since $x$ has to be an integer, and $5^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is irrational, we have to prove that $(5z^3-y^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is rational, since an irrational times a rational is always irrational. That proves that $x$ is not an integer by contradiction. However, I'm not sure if my logic is even right, and if it is, I'm not sure how to continue.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the help, I have accepted an answer as correct.

Comment: It’s possible for a product of two irrationals to be irrational as well, so it is not *required* that the second factor be rational for this product to be irrational. In other words, *if* $(5z^3-y^3)^{1/3}$ were rational, your conclusion would follow (it is sufficient), but even if it is irrational, you would not be able to conclude otherwise (it is not *necessary*, but you are claiming it is necessary).

Comment: First show that each of $x,y,z$ must be divisible by $5$, then...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, right. Then, should I split it into two cases? Or is proof by contradiction not the best way here in the first place?

Comment: Your approach is not very good, precisely because you won’t be able to conclude much. I would instead suggest noting that you can factor out any common factors, so you may assume that $x$, $y$ and $z$, if nonzero, have no common factors other than $1$ and $-1$; then think about the highest power of $5$ that can divide $x$ (since $x$ *must* be a multiple of five, given the equation).

Comment: @abiessu's idea is the only one worth considering I think :-)

Comment: I haven't read the idea of @abiessu except after posting my answer to find out it was what I did :-)

Comment: @FruDe is my answer alright for you? If there's a problem don't hesitate to ask :-)

Comment: That's fine @AnasA.Ibrahim. I upvoted your post. Even I could come up with the same idea under my own steam. No reason to suspect you wouldn't, too.

Comment: @AnasA.Ibrahim Yes, I got it. I marked it as correct :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think one usually takes roots usually when solving a number theory equation like this. You don't have to consider it this way when working with integers.

Here's a solution:
$$x^3=5(5z^3−y^3) \implies5|x^3 \implies5|x \implies x=5x_1$$
for some integer $x_1$, this gives
$$125x_1^3=5(5z^3−y^3) \iff 25x_1^3=5z^3-y^3 \iff 5(z^3-5x_1^3)=y^3$$
$$\implies5|y^3 \implies 5|y \implies y=5y_1$$
for some integer $y_1$
$$\implies 25y_1^3=z^3-5x_1^3 \iff5(5y_1^3+x_1^3)=z^3 \implies5|z^3 \implies5|z\implies z=5z_1$$
$$\implies25z_1^3=5y_1^3+x_1^3$$
and we turned back to the original equation but with each variable divided by $5$. You can continue on this method infinitely and end up with the same equation but with variables divided by $5$. However, you can't have integers that can be divided by $5$ infinitely except $x=y=z=0 \ \  \Box.$